# What does Adjusting mix and spend mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/match_2#mix_idmg_3

> Adjusting mix and spend to where the consumer is now (go digital, ensure full coverage of bottom-funnel marketing and demand capture, think region-by-region)

[Source](https://www.mckinsey.com/business-functions/marketing-and-sales/our-insights/the-great-consumer-shift-ten-charts-that-show-how-us-shopping-behavior-is-changing?cid=soc-app)

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is talking about changes to marketing practices. [Marketing mix](https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/definition/marketing-mix#:%7E:text=Definition%3A%20The%20marketing%20mix%20refers,%2C%20Product%2C%20Promotion%20and%20Place.&text=Pricing%20can%20also%20be%20used,the%20image%20of%20a%20product.) is a reference to the the four P's of marketing- Price, Product, Promotion and Place.

Spend probably means the budget allocated to marketing activities.